# "Embed" an assembly 'A' in multiple libraries, so that a consumer cannot see A, but any of the libraries can

Tags: c#, libraries

I have a set of libraries that can be consumed independently (compositionally), but each of them share certain functions that I'd like to define in a single 'core' library.

I don't want those functions visible to the consumer, which they would be if I ask the consumer to directly reference Core as a prerequisite.

Is there a way to give each library access to a single copy of Core, in a way that does not make Core visible to the consumer? Like, can I somehow 'embed' Core if any of the libraries are used, without having multiple copies of Core in memory?

Lib.Core

```
(component-visible) class Utility
{
    int CalculateSomething(int input) { }
}
```

Lib.Abc

```
using Lib.Core;

public class Foo()
{
    public Foo(int seed)
    {
        Value = Core.Utility.CalculateSomething(seed);
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Lib.Xyz

```
using Lib.Core;
...
```

Consumer

```
using Lib.Abc;
using Lib.Xyz;

public class Bar
{
    public int GetValue(int seed)
    {
        return new Foo(seed).Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio you can add your "Core" code files as linked files (Add > Existing > dropdown on Add button).  This will allow the code for "Core" to be compiled into each library and still give you a single point of maintenance for "Core".

The downside is that if you add new functionality you will have to recompile each library that references "Core" files.  But that shouldn't be too bad - as a separate assembly Core would have to be compiled and distributed for changes anyhow.

Comment: I think that sounds reasonable. The functions really are just helper methods (clamping numeric values, etc.) that I use frequently, but I don't want to expose as if they are features of the product. So this way I could fix bugs in them, release an update to each library, and it would fit into the general improvements category. So, the runtime would ensure that only a single copy of Core was being used across the assemblies?

Comment: Well technically there would be no "Core" any longer.  You may group your code in a "Core" project, but that project would never get compiled.  "Core" would get compiled into each of your libraries.